# Comparing strings in foreach loop doesn't return correct array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, string-comparison

I have to create a specialized method to handle how author names are displayed.  What I need to happen is to match the author roles, and display the lead author ($author) with any secondary authors ($author2) that have the same role.

In the example the case below, the author array that should be returned is ["Smith", "Jones"].

Input array example:

```
$author = "Smith";
$author2 = ["Jones", "Berry", "Mitchell"];
$auth_role = "";
$auth2_role = [ "", "editor", "editor"];
```

Right now, the method is only outputting the primary author ($author), but not any of the additional authors ($author2). When I put print statements into the code, it showed that it was returning at the first return statement.

The method I've written so far is as follows. I think the code is skipping through or over the foreach loop.

```
/**
 * Get the authors for display.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAuthors()
{
   $leader = $this->marcRecord->getLeader();
   $bibLvl = $leader[7];
   $over_title = $this->fields['item_title_txt'];

   $author2 = $this->getSecondaryAuthors();
   $author = $this->getPrimaryAuthor();
   $auth_role = $this->getPrimaryAuthorRole();
   $auth2_role = $this->getSecondaryAuthorRoles();

   $authdisplay = [$author];

   if (!empty($over_title) && ($bibLvl=='a')) {
    $i=0;
    foreach ($auth2_role as $field){
      if ($field == $auth_role) {
        $authdisplay = [$field];
      }
      $i++;
    }
    return $authdisplay;
  }
  return $authdisplay;
}
```

Do you have any tips on how to get the method to display the list of authors correctly (i.e., in the example array case above, that would be ["Smith", "Jones"];)? Thank you.

Comment: What's the value of `$over_title` and `$bibLvl`?

Comment: Btw, you're not doing anything with `$author2` ... at the very least I would expect you attempt to access the first element if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your if with this:

```
if (!empty($over_title) && ($bibLvl=='a')) {
    foreach ($auth2_role as $key=>$field){
        if ($field == $auth_role) {
            $authdisplay[] = $author2[$key];
        }
    }
    return $authdisplay;
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Smith
    [1] => Jones
)
```